# Expected Value of Function Multiplication?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Given: $N$ ~ $Geo(p_N$) and $X_i$ ~ $Geo(p_X)$
>
> Where $N$ is independent on $X_i$, and all $X_i$s are i.i.d
>
> We define: $Z=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$
>
> Q: Find m.g.f for Z

My Try:

$M_Z(t)=E[e^{tz}]=E[E[e^{tz}|N]]=E[E[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^NX_i}]]=E[\prod_{i=1}^N E[e^{tx_i}]]=$

But I'm stuck here, any help?

Comment: Explicitly compute $E[e^{tX_i}]$ for each $i$. They will actually be the same quantity, so the next step will look like $E[(\cdots)^N]$.

Comment: @angryavian that's where I failed, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Just start with the definition of expectation, $E[e^{tX_1}] = \sum_k e^{tk} P(X_1=k) = \cdots$

Comment: @angryavian I failed again, it's impossible to calculate this you get $\sum_k e^{tk}(1-P_x)^{k-1}P_x = P_x \sum_k e^{tk}(1-P_x)^{k-1}$ how to continue from here?

Comment: You can rearrange things to get something of the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{k-1}$ which is a geometric series.